# Match even numbers containing at least one "5" digit

Tags: regex

I have to find regular expression defining any even number, with at least one "5" digit inside. I've been thinking about:

```
(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)* 5 (0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)* (0+2+4+6+8)
```

Will this work? Is there a way to make it shorter?

Well, I'm not sure if this is the right website to post this question...but the tag exists :P

Comment: Does `+` mean `|` in your notation?

Comment: Looks good, but you should decide on a notation first (in theoretical CS you normally use `|`).

Comment: Do you have to cover the issue that numbers may not start with `0`?

Comment: @Howard mathematically speaking 012345 = 12345 (so it should be irrelevant)

Comment: What if I remove all +/|, making this a concatenation? Will it be the same?

Comment: @Nirk Now try this with your favorite C compiler.

Comment: @Howard the problem reads as if it was from an introductory automata class, not from an actual programming class

Comment: @Nirk And also not from an introductory math class ;-) I think it is ok to remind of corner cases in a comment - and numbers usually don't start with 0 - also not in automata classes.

Comment: It's just an issue of notation. Stricktly speaking, `056` _is_ a valid number and it satisfies the criteria.

Comment: Just got an idea. @user2252786, if you are a programmer you can use this task to learn test-driven-development. First right down a set of tests for your task, then make a regexp and test it using your unit-tests. Killing two birds with one stone ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexp looks good. I don't think you can make it shorter (if we are speaking about *theoretical* regexps; real programming languages have shortcuts like `[0-9]` or `\d` for any digit).

As pointed out by others your regexp will also match numbers starting from any number of zeroes. If you don't want this, you will of course try to match the first digit with `(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)`, but now you've got a special case: what if the first digit is `5`? So you'll have to add more branches.

Your regexp is fine, but I think that making it match only numbers without leading zeroes is a good exercise and you should try it anyway, even if your task doesn't require this.

---

Here is a general advice. Problems requiring you to create regular expressions are best wil help of [Test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). That is, *before* trying to write the regexp you create a set of tests for it. It has a number of benefits:

1. If you've written many tests and you regexp passed them, you'll be almost sure you've got it write.
2. Quality of your tests will be way higher if you write them *before* creating regexps.
3. Seeing your freshly handcrafted regexp immediately pass your set of thorough tests makes you happy, trust me =).

Comment: "If you've written many tests and you regexp passed them, you'll be almost sure you've got it write." is this a pun comparing tests to spell checkers?